# C# queue - how to add structure to each queue spot

Tags: c#-4.0

C# queue and in each location have a collection of an integer and a string? I know how to create a queue of integers or strings but how do I create one that has more than one data type in each queue spot?

```
struct ABC { int val1; int val2; } 

static void Main(string[] args) { 
  System.Collections.Generic.Queue<ABC> queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<ABC>(); 
  queue.Enqueue(ABC);
 // ...
}
```

Not sure how to add ABC to the queue, or how to put integers in val1 and val2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of the struct, assign values to it, and then queue it.  The second issue is that you are not using public fields/properties.

```
struct ABC { public int val1; public int val2; } 

static void Main(string[] args) { 
    System.Collections.Generic.Queue<ABC> queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<ABC>();

    ABC queuable = new ABC() { val1 = 3, val2 = 39};

    queue.Enqueue(queuable);
    // ...
}
```

Of course, you can also add `using` statements to import the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace to clean up the code a bit, too.